# Tag <provider> attribute authorities has invalid character '$'. AndroidManifest.xml /FacebookActivity

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I'm trying to create a library project from `facebook sdk` in `Eclipse`.
This error shows:

> Tag  attribute authorities has invalid character
>   '$'.  AndroidManifest.xml /FacebookActivity   line 44 Android AAPT
>   Problem

Here is the part of the `Manifest`:

```
<provider
    android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.FacebookInitProvider"
    android:exported="false" />
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to use manifest placeholders. AFAIK, that is not supported in Eclipse. Note that Eclipse itself is not supported by Google anymore for Android app development.

Either:

- Replace all occurrences of `${applicationId}` with your app's package name, or
- Switch to Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

So when building your app, the **Gradle build merges all manifest** files into a single manifest file that's packaged into your APK. 
But the **Ant build doesn't merge manifests by default**. And you have a choice to copy activity and provider tags from each library's manifest that you have in dependencies of your app manually, or to try enable Manifest merger by placing "manifestmerger.enabled=true" into the "project.properties" of your app's project. 
I use the first case. Then I add the second provider tag to my AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<!--provider from facebook sdk manifest-->
<provider
    android:authorities="com.example.hellofacebook.FacebookInitProvider"
    android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Just put your app package name in place of ${applicationId}, and don't forget to replace ${applicationId} in library's manifest, to be able to compile it as a dependency of your app.